# Wrong Hibernate type mapping with Struts 2

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, hibernate-mapping

I have a example application in Struts 2 with Hibernate. I began to test the datepicker from Struts 2, but for some reason it saves as a `bytea`, even when the Java code treats it as a `String` (because Struts 2 returns it as a String) and later as an `LocalDate`.

This is happening on the database (PostgreSQL):

[image: result on database]

I have a `UserPOJO` class for DTO:

```
public class UserPOJO {
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String cargo;
    private String nasc;
```

Then, on the User constructor, I convert it to `LocalDate`:

```
public User(UserPOJO pojo) {
        this.name = pojo.getName();
        this.password = pojo.getPassword();
        this.email = pojo.getEmail();
        String s = pojo.getNasc().substring(0,10);
        this.nasc = LocalDate.parse(s);
        this.cargo = new Cargo();
        this.cargo.setId(Integer.parseInt(pojo.getCargo()));
    }
```

When I retrieve the data from the database to show it onscreen, it works fine. But I don't know why it is saving as `bytea` and why it works on retrieving the data. I want to save it as a `date` on the database.

I am using Java 8, Struts 2.3.15.1, Hibernate 4.3.5.Final, PostgreSQL 11 and Struts 2 DOJO Plugin 2.3.4.1.

Comment: DOJO plugin is deprecated, there's also many ways to unmarshall objects in struts2.

Answer (score 0):

In Database, datatype changed to Date.
check if it works.